# Square API - Object Update for Multiple Locations

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm trying to update objects using the endpoint [BatchRetrieveCatalogObjects](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-batchupsertcatalogobjects) (POST /v2/catalog/batch-upsert).

When I post the request, I get the error

```
[type] => bad_request
[message] => Multi-location support is unavailable for this endpoint. Parameter `merchant_id` must correspond to a single-location account, not a business account
```

How can I update objects if there are multiple locations and if items have location overrides?

Is there another endpoint that I can use?

[UpsertCatalogObject](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-upsertcatalogobject) (POST /v2/catalog/object) does not work either. Same error.

Below is a sample request payload:

```
Array
(
    [idempotency_key] => 1122334455667788
    [batches] => Array
        (
            [type] => ITEM
            [id] => 5BLFIPNYBTDD5ARZYQU4K7SV
            [item_data] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>  Honey Mead
                    [description] => Mead is an adult beverage brewed exclusively with honey. 
                    [category_id] => OIMGQF7DCO7W6SEXEMKGIJK5
                )

            [variations] => Array
                (
                    [type] => ITEM_VARIATION
                    [id] => BEQZ6FXAJACGW55RRZBMXDEI
                    [item_variation_data] => Array
                        (
                            [item_id] => 5BLFIPNYBTDD5ARZYQU4K7SV
                            [name] => Case (24 bottles)
                            [pricing_type] => FIXED_PRICING
                            [ordinal] => 4
                            [price_money] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => 11900
                                )

                            [location_overrides] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [location_id] => 81J6E4K21KGC9
                                            [price_money] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [amount] => 11900
                                                )

                                            [pricing_type] => FIXED_PRICING
                                            [track_inventory] => 1
                                            [inventory_alert_type] => LOW_QUANTITY
                                            [inventory_alert_threshold] => 15
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Additional Notes for Clarification:

I'm trying to edit the price at either the variation or location_overrides level. I get the error for any call to the endpoint. I think the Square API developers don't allow any calls to the endpoint for any multi-unit locations. I also cannot delete locations either on the website or API. They only allow you to hide locations, which I did. But the error still persists.

I tried the v1 endpoint and get strange results. V1 & V2 use different variation_id. So if I pass a v2 variation_id to the v1 endpoint, it creates a new variation rather than updating it. The new variation then displays a new field called catalog_v1_id. Then when I try to delete the variation on the website, it disappears from the website view but still exists as an active item when I call the v2 list variation endpoint. I'm thinking this API has a whole host of bugs and is not ready for prime time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change that involves variation between locations? You can have an item that only shows up on X locations, but they must have the same data for all of those locations (besides inventory count, which is not the endpoint being referenced here). If you change an item price that currently is in location X and Y, for instance, it will update the price in both locations.

Comment: By the way, if you happen to use the V1 item create (instead of V2), you would receive this error if you pass in your merchant id, rather than your `location_id`. You can find your `location_id` in your Square Dashboard > Apps > Manage App > Locations. You can also call `ListLocations` which will have the ids.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the price at either the variation or location_overrides level. I get the error for any call to the endpoint. I think the Square API developers don't allow any calls to the endpoint for any multi-unit locations. I also cannot delete locations either on the website or API. They only allow you to hide locations, which I did. But the error still persists.

Comment: I tried the v1 endpoint and get strange results. V1 & V2 use different variation_id. So if I pass a v2 variation_id to the v1 endpoint, it creates a new variation rather than updating it. The new item then displays a new field called catalog_v1_id. Then when I try to delete the variation on the website, it disappears from the website view but still exists as an active item when I call the v2 list variation endpoint. I'm thinking this API has a whole host of bugs and is not ready for prime time.

Comment: As far as I know, this error should only be occurring while using V1, not V2. With that said, to help better troubleshoot this issue, can you please create a support ticket and reference this StackOverflow question? https://squareup.com/help/us/en/contact?panel=BF53A9C8EF68 Alternatively, you can join our Slack channel: https://squ.re/2Hks3YE

Comment: This is a v2 issue. I just opened a ticket on the link you provided.